# I am trying to use whatsapp message template but I'm getting this error

Tags: python, whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

0

I am trying to use whatsapp message template but I'm getting this error, the formatting of whatsapp template call to action is causing this error.

Every time I try i get this error message:

<ClientResponse(https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/5454354/messages) [400 Bad Request]> <CIMultiDictProxy('Vary': 'Origin', 'x-business- use-case-usage': '{"100fd54659436463398":[{"type":"whatsapp","call_count":1,"total_cputime":1,"total_time":1,"estimated_time_to_regain_access":0}]}', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'WWW-Authenticate': '**OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "(#100) Invalid parameter"**', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'facebook-api-version': 'v17.0', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=15552000; preload', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Cache-Control': 'no-store', 'Expires': 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT', 'x-fb-request-id': 'AZV5usY95HxmwAqnTAhlNbk', 'x-fb-trace-id': 'DzTUMuhPUrJ', 'x-fb-rev': '1007968251', 'X-FB-Debug': 'c/rw2NdFtA2d/TjUL98BN4Nu95KbW8xSG0gLuwQK661ZAtGcHYfdZzqH+m9YOTCNYHng5BI4ASO605QLW0eoVL7g==', 'Date': 'Thu, 03 Aug 2023 13:40:34 GMT', 'Alt-Svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=86400', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Length': '236')>
I'm getting this because of Button:

return json.dumps({ "messaging_product": "whatsapp", "to": recipient, "type": "template", "template": { "name": "template", "language": { "code": "en" }, "components": [{ "type": "header", "parameters": [{ "type": "text", "text": name }] }, { "type": "body", "parameters": [ { "type": "text", "text": text }, ] }, { "type": "button", "parameters": [{ "type": "text", "text": link }] }] } })
Message preview: whatsapp message template

I tried reading documentations and things, but can't find a perfect solution.

tried reading docs but can't get any help, fb also included and example of that also.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.